# Strange result from baking normal map

Tags: normals, baking, mirror, normal-map, artifacts

I can't seem to figure out what is happening here. A bug possibly? [image: normal bake]

I went from a normal bake result to this. The only thing that changed between the two bakes was the use of a mirror modifier on the cage. However the vert/face/tri count/structure remained the same for both the cage and low-poly. I'm 100% sure that this is caused by the cage and possibly the mirror function.

This has happened to me before >[same issue](https://blenderartists.org/t/possible-bug-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong/702869).  In this instance, I used the symmetry function in edit mode.

The fix was to simply remake the cage from copy/pasting the low-poly. Yet this is hardly a fix because it requires scraping a finely tuned cage.

I'm still troubleshooting to see what exactly the issue is but I was hoping someone could give some insight into this problem.

***EDIT:***
**I believe I found what causes this issue. I did a test where I edited a section of the low-poly, duplicated the edited section, separated the section, then joined the section to the cage mesh and merged the correct vertices. After baking I get the strange result in the picture. I found a workaround by duplicating the low-poly into its own object, then using a shrinkwrap modifier to match the "malfunctioning cage" in order to preserve the changes I made. Although the topology is exactly the same between the two cages, only the latter yeilds correct results. The only difference specifically being different object data. This leads me to believe it is a bug.**

Comment: Do you have multiple uv maps?

Comment: yes, (15characterminum)

Comment: have you selected the correct one?

Comment: As far I know, yes. I was unaware that you could select the wrong UV map. I had the assumption that the one you have selected is the "correct one"

Comment: I've made that mistake a couple of times but I think this can be worked around by using the correct uv mapping in your node setup ( I think ). But if you already have selected the correct one, have you tried applying the mirror modifier? Im not too sure how blender works with loose parts for cages tho. Also make sure that there is no overlapping UV's. The baker does not know how to deal with overlaps.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a consistent method to recreate the problem but I'm confidant the uv maps are not related.